# It is necessary to solve the problem when sending a request to the controller to receive json. Error sending to postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, asp.net-core

I made a small service that should send a request to a third-party resource, after which I accept json from this resource. Implemented on ASP.NET С#

The error is that I send a post request through a postman, then there is a long download, after which the answer comes out: "Could not get response" "Error: read ECONNRESET"
The application is running. launched on  http://localhost:"port issued asp.net"
how to send a request correctly? If you see any problems in the code, please tell me about them so that I can understand and fix.

CODE:

request:

```
{
"str":"d02d355e,b4ad,7120,8e78,4a0904b37179",
"token":"i116ie9qn7vpa0k"
    
}
```

SERVICE:

```
 public class ServiceFromGetStatus
    {

       private IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

        Attributes attributes;

        string errorMsg;
        public ServiceFromGetStatus( IHttpClientFactory httpClient)
        {
            
            _clientFactory = httpClient;
        }

   //oneMethod 
        public static string[] ShowAllOrder(string liststring)
        {
            string[] masString = liststring.Split("[ ,]+");

            return masString;
        }


  //twoMethod 
        public  async Task<List<ShowModelAttributes>> sendRestArrayOrderId(StrAndToken str)
        {
          string[] mas =  ShowAllOrder(str.str);

            var restLst = new List<Attributes>();

            foreach (string i in mas)
            {
                var urlFormat = string.Format("https://example.ru/rest/getStatus.do?token={0}&orderId={0}/", str.token, i);

                var paramsDto = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, urlFormat);
                var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(paramsDto);
                
                   attributes  = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Attributes>();
                    restLst.Add(attributes);                
            }
            return toShowModel(restLst);
        }

 //threeMethod 
       public List<ShowModelAttributes> toShowModel(List<Attributes> listDto)
        {

            var bb = new List<ShowModelAttributes>();

            foreach (Attributes i in listDto)
            {

                if (i.orderStatus == 2)
                {

                    bb.Add(new ShowModelAttributes(i.orderNumber,
                            i.orderStatus,
                            i.amount,
                            i.Info.depositedAmount,
                            i.depositedDate,
                            i.cardAuthInfo.Pan,
                            i.terminal,
                            i.authRefNum,
                            i.cardAuthInfo.Code
                            ));
                }
                else if (i.orderStatus == 1)
                {
                    bb.Add(new ShowModelAttributes(i.orderNumber,
                            i.orderStatus,
                            i.amount,
                            i.Info.depositedAmount,
                            i.depositedDate,
                            i.cardAuthInfo.Pan,
                            i.terminal,
                            i.authRefNum,
                            i.cardAuthInfo.approvalCode
                               ));
                }

            }
            return bb;
        }
```

MODEL:

```
 public class Attributes
   
    {

        public string errorCode { get; set; }
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
        public string orderNumber { get; set; }
        public int orderStatus { get; set; }
        public int actionCode { get; set; }
        public string actionCodeDescription { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public long date { get; set; }
        public long depositedDate { get; set; }
        public string orderDescription { get; set; }
        public string ip { get; set; }
        public List<object> Params { get; set; }
        public List<object> trans { get; set; }
        public List<Attributes> attributes { get; set; }
        public CardAuthInfo cardAuthInfo { get; set; }
        public long authDateTime { get; set; }
        public string terminal { get; set; }
        public string authRefNum { get; set; }
        public Info info { get; set; }
        public Inter inter { get; set; }

}

public class CardAuthInfo
{
    public string Pan { get; set; }
    public string expiration { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string pan { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string paymentState { get; set; }
    public int approvedAmount { get; set; }
    public int depositedAmount { get; set; }
    public int refundedAmount { get; set; }
}

public class Inter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }

    }
```

SturtUp:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Сonfiguration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Сonfiguration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

           
            services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContex>(o => o.UseNpgsql(Сonfiguration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
              ));
     //       services.AddScoped<DataBaseContex>(p => p.GetService<DataBaseContex>());
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddScoped<ServiceFromGetStatus>();
            services.AddHttpClient<ServiceFromGetStatus>();
            services.AddScoped<Attributes>();
            services.AddScoped<ShowModelAttributes>();
            services.AddScoped<StrAndToken>();
           
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
               
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
       }
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[Route("api/command")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {

        ServiceFromGetStatus serviceFromGetStatus;

        public ValuesController(ServiceFromGetStatus serviceFromGetStatus)
        {
            this.serviceFromGetStatus = serviceFromGetStatus;
        }    

            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<List<ShowModelAttributes>> showModels([FromBody]StrAndToken str)
            {
               return await serviceFromGetStatus.sendRestArrayOrderId(str);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code by setting a breakpoint? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/quickstart-debug-aspnet?view=vs-2019

Comment: @NoahStahl I put it. Postman is loaded for a long time with the inscription "Sending request ..", then an error, and the application still works

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue, I think it's an issue with Postman...